# 'new' operator log warning when creating a GameObject, how to get around it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, new-operator

Im wondering about something I am doing that is causing this well known warning:

```
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed. MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all.
```

I know that I can simply use the `Addcomponent<T>` to avoid that logwarning. I also understand that unity does not allow anything inheriting from monobehaviour to be instantiated ([ref](https://answers.unity.com/questions/653904/you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-using-the-2.html)).

It should be said however that right now the tests providing this logwarning are all working fine, I just want to get rid of the warning.

This is an example of a test that gives this error.

```
[Test]
public void HandleHoverSetsCurrentInteractableOnInteractor()
{
    /// Arrange
    GameObject actor;
    actor = new GameObject();
    actor.AddComponent<XRController>();

    GameObject actable;
    actable = new GameObject();
    Handle h = actable.AddComponent<Handle>();
    h.Hover(actor.GetComponent<IActor>());

    /// Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actor.GetComponent<IActor>().currentInteractable);
}
```

Now as mentioned earlier this works exactly as I would expect and it is creating the GameObject and testing the Hover functionality. It's just giving me that logwarning every time I do this. I am therefore wondering if there is a correct way of doing this? preferably without the logwarning.

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov no I wouldn't say so since the link is actually using it on a MonoBehaviour while at least in the provided snippet the only usage is `new GameObject` which should be fine ..

Comment: Can you tell in which line exactly the warning is thrown?

Comment: Is the log being shown on Unity's console or in the IDE (if so, which IDE do you use?)

Comment: Its being shown in the unity Console and the lines giving the error are the "new GameObject()" ones

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) is definitely **not** inherited from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) !! It further has a [constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html) and the usage of `new GameObject();` is completely valid please check the API before wanting to close a question ;)

Comment: What is the full stacktrace for the warning?